# Printing an HTML email that contains a table longer than 1 page

Tags: html, printing, internet-explorer-7

When I try printing an HTML-email with a table that stretches multiple pages then Windows-Mail and IE7 will only print whatever fits on the first page but Firefox prints everything just fine.

Any thoughts how I can make the Microsoft products print the entire thing?

Regards, Pieter

Comment: When printing from IE7 are you selecting all pages or is the default page selection set to current page?

Comment: how is this related to programming?

Comment: @Can: its related in that how one codes the generation of HTML in the email may allow better printing.

Comment: all pages.

Well if i have to change the php-script that generates this html-email so it will generate correct html-code which will make windows-email handle the printing correctly that makes it slightly programming related, doesnt it :-D

Comment: @Anthony: I'm not sure. OP doesn't state he generates the HTML himself.

Comment: @Pieter: More details please, limit to one aspect, for example printing in IE7. I've not see this problem before

Comment: @Overbeeke: yes, if you're generating the HTML, then it's programming related.

Comment: http://www.ipdemo.nl/newsletter.html : try print it with "all" selected in IE7

Comment: Doesn't this question belong to superuser.com?

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for a one-off email, you can try one of the following:

1) Click on file > print to ensure you get the print dialog box
2) Ensure that "all pages" is selected in the print dialog
3) Confirm the print job

or

1) Copy and paste the email into another application, such as Word and print the document from there.

If this is not a one-off issue, you could look at generating the information as a printable attachment, for example PDF format - which gives you more control over print-layout than HTML does.

Answer (score 0):

I just dove into the problem again and found out that Internet Explorer and windows mail as well (same html engine?) cannot handle nested tables (a table inside the cell of another table) very well when it comes to printing them.

Removing the nested tables from the html-email solved the problem (and created another one but i was able to solve the layout issues without nested tables nicely ;) )